# How to create multiple choice drop down phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

I want create multi choice drop down in phpspreadsheet but i don't found how to make it.

```php
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setDataValidation(
            'P2:P100',
            (new DataValidation())
                ->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST)
                ->setFormula1('"A, B, C"')
                ->setFormula2('"D, E, F"')
                ->setAllowBlank(false)
                ->setShowInputMessage(true)
                ->setShowErrorMessage(true)
                ->setShowDropDown(true)
                ->setErrorTitle('Erreur')
                ->setError(translate('general_note_import_export_gabarit_organization',true))
                ->setPromptTitle('Note')
                ->setPrompt(translate('general_note_import_export_gabarit_organization',true))
        );
```

Comment: descibe your question. what you mean by spread sheet? and where do ypu want dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is impossible. PhpSpreadsheet don't support drop downs.